# Which preposition is correct and why? To or For?

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following sentence is correct and why?

- This letter is very important **to** your admission.
- This letter is very important **for** your admission.

Answer (score 2):

Either. It depends on context.

> This letter is very important to your admission.

The contents of this letter, the information in it, will be used to determine your suitability.

> This letter is very important for your admission.

If you don't supply the letter, you won't be admitted.

Comment: I think you can only use *for* ... "This letter is very important *for* (the purpose of considering) your admission."